# Equivalent of screen method in less with sass

Tags: css, sass, less

In LESS I was using `screen($color1, $color2)`.

From the doc `Do the opposite of multiply. The result is a brighter color.`
http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-blending-screen

I am looking for the equivalent in sass. What can I use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SASS it's `mix` [module](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#mix-instance_method).

```
mix(#f00, #00f) => #7f007f
mix(#f00, #00f, 25%) => #3f00bf
mix(rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5), #00f) => rgba(63, 0, 191, 0.75)
```

Comment: Where does this answer the question? I don't see which of these is equivalent to `screen`. Sass's `mix` is equivalent to less's `average`.

Comment: @LukeTaylor there'r no any equivalent for `screen` in SASS. But with using `mix`, and third parameter `weight`, you can create any of this modules.

Comment: My understanding was that screen does more than mix with weight, it somehow multiplies the values? How do I do that?